# How to handle PUT endpoint with immutable resource

Tags: rest, http, server

A microservice I develop exposes a single endpoint, PUT /deployments/{uuid} . The endpoint is used to initiate a potentially expensive deployment operation, so we only ever want it to happen once, which is why we chose PUT + UUID over POST (for uniqueness). The deployment is immutable, so it can never be updated, so we currently raise an exception if the PUT is called more than once with the same uuid.

As a person who loves bikeshedding and therefore cares *deeply* about restfulness, this grinds my gears. PUT is supposed to be idempotent, so raising an exception after making the same request multiple times is an antipattern. However, we have a requirement to not allow sequential identical requests to generate new deployments, so the usual POST is out.

While the best solution is one that works, I'd like ours to be a little more elegant, if possible. I've posited a POST with the UUID in the payload, but my team seems to think that's worse than the current solution. I'm considering just returning a 200 OK from a PUT to the same UUID rather than a 201 CREATED, but I'm not sure if that has the same problem as non-idempotent-put in not semantically conveying the information I want.

Is there a "best solution" here? Or am I doomed to be "that guy" on my team if I pursue this further (joke's on you i'm already that guy).

**tl;dr** What is the correct RESTful API signature for a /deployments endpoint that is immutable, and required to not allow the same request to be processed twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idempotent does not mean "2 identical requests should yield the same response". It means: "The server state after 2 identical requests should be the same as when only 1 is made".

A similar example, if you call `DELETE` on a resource and get a `204 No Content` back, and call `DELETE` again and get a `404`, this doesn't violate the idempotency requirement. After the second delete the resource is still removed, just like it was after the first.

So multiple identical idempotent requests are allowed to give different responses.

That said though, I think it might be nicer to the second identical request to also get a 2xx status back. It doesn't have to be the same as the first.

The use-case is if a client sent a HTTP request but got disconnected before it got a response. The client *should* retry and if the server detects the request is the same as the first, the server can just give the client a success response (but don't do anything).

This is generally a good idea, because if the client got an error back for the second request, it might be harder to know if the request failed because it succeeded earlier, or for other reasons.

That all being said though, there is also a way here to have your cake and eat it too.

A client *could* send the following header along with the `PUT` request:

```
If-None-Match: *
```

If the client omits the header, you can always return `424 Precondition Required`.

If the resource does not yet exist, it's a success response. If the resource was created earlier, you can return `412 Precondition Failed`.

Using this mechanism a client has a standard way to figure out that the request failed because a successful one was made earlier.

Comment: Oh wow that distinction on idempotency is an important one to not have known, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PUT#responses), `PUT` is the best method to use. The response should be `201` when it triggers the deployment, and either `200` or `204` when nothing is changed. It shouldn't be `POST` because calling a `POST` endpoint twice should trigger the effect both times.